# Linq query to get count by status

Tags: c#, linq

I want to count the items status wise in a datatable.

My Datatable looks like

```
Date , Tkt Status
1/2/13    open
1/2/13    open
2/2/13    open
2/2/13    closed
2/2/13    closed
3/3/13    in-progress
4/3/13    closed
```

I want another datatable with below data in the format

```
Date, Open, Closed, in-progress
1/2/13   2        0            0
2/2/13   1        2            0
3/3/13   0        0            1
4/3/13   0        1            0
```

I want it to be done using Linq.

My attempt so far

dataQuery.Query = "Yes";

```
                    dataQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Created' /><FieldRef Name='tckPrty' /><FieldRef Name='tckStat' />";
                    dataQuery.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
                    tktData = tktList.GetItems(dataQuery).GetDataTable();

                    var newData = from row in tktData.AsEnumerable()
                                  where groupDate(row.Field<string>("tckStat"))
                                          group row by row.Field<string>("Created") into Status
                                          orderby Status.Key
                                          select new
                                          {
                                              key = Status.Key,
                                              values = Status,
                                              count = Status.Count()
                                          };

                    foreach (var item in newData)
                    {
                        foreach (string s in tktStatus)
                        {
                            chartData.Rows.Add(item.key,item.count);
                        }
                    }
```

The function goes here

static bool groupDate(string skill)
        {
            bool value = false;

```
            if (skill== "open")
            {
                value = true;
            }
            else
            {
                value = false;
            }

            return value;
    }
```

Comment: I want a ferrari, a new house and a sixpack. I won't get any of these unless i put some work into it though - I suggest you attempt the solution, then ask for help on specific problems.

Comment: I have attempted the solution but I am stuck with making the status as columns and getting the count under it. i Will post my linq here. and dont judge people too early it might be that one does not want to confuse others by giving lots of codes at once.

Comment: It's not judgement. You stated in the question I want xyz. SO is not a code writing service, so if you provide nothing you will get nothing. see [Asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: if you know the solution then provide otherwise let other answer. and don't make it look dirty.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously we don't have your data table to work with, so I built an array from your example.

```
var lines = @"Date , Tkt Status
1/2/13    open
1/2/13    open
2/2/13    open
2/2/13    closed
2/2/13    closed
3/3/13    in-progress
4/3/13    closed".Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).Select(x => new { Date = x[0], Status = x[1] }).ToArray();
```

Then, you can use LINQ like this to group it:

```
var grouped = lines.GroupBy(l => l.Date).Select(g => new {
    Date = g.Key,
    Open = g.Count(l => l.Status == "open"),
    Closed = g.Count(l => l.Status == "closed"),
    InProgress = g.Count(l => l.Status == "in-progress")
}).ToArray();
```

Output:

```
Date    Open Closed InProgress
1/2/13  2    0      0
2/2/13  1    2      0
3/3/13  0    0      1
4/3/13  0    1      0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Keith. I will try the code and let you know. Though i have one issue that I really don't know what data can come in status column. It will be dynamic. And sceondly my Datatable is basically coming from Sharepoint list data having date and Status column.

Comment: @MdRehanMoazzam this answer might help you with dynamic columns: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26719396/4473405