# group XDocument by multiple nodes (dynamic)

Tags: asp.net-core, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

I have below data coming in as DataTable. If I directly convert it to XML I get nice xdocument object.

[image]

However problem is I need to group it by first 4 columns so that XML is shown as below. I know of only three nodes 'Segment', 'Price' and 'Qty' rest columns in datatable could be dynamic and cannot use hardcoded names (except for above 3)

```
<ROOT>
<ROW>
    <Col1>CESLP</Col1>
    <Col2>MRP</Col2>
    <Col3>372</Col3>
    <Date>20040101</Date>
    <BID_INTERVALS>
        <SEGMENT>1</SEGMENT>
        <Price>10</Price>
        <QTY>5</QTY>
    </BID_INTERVALS>
    <BID_INTERVALS>
        <SEGMENT>2</SEGMENT>
        <Price>15</Price>
        <QTY>6</QTY>
    </BID_INTERVALS>
</ROW>
<ROW>
    <Col1>CESLP</Col1>
    <Col2>MRP</Col2>
    <Col3>372</Col3>
    <Date>20040102</Date>
    <BID_INTERVALS>
        <SEGMENT>1</SEGMENT>
        <Price>11</Price>
        <QTY>5</QTY>
    </BID_INTERVALS>
    <BID_INTERVALS>
        <SEGMENT>2</SEGMENT>
        <Price>14.5</Price>
        <QTY>6</QTY>
    </BID_INTERVALS>
</ROW>
```

Any solution? I'm stuck for quite some time, tried xdocument group by 'except' but didn't worked for me.

**Edit1:**

I'm using below code to group the records (using solution [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658978/c-sharp-linq-how-to-build-group-by-clause-dynamically)

```
dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(r => new NTuple<object>(from column in colNames select r[column]))
                .Select(g => g.CopyToDataTable()).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you share the input XML as well as the desired XML -- i.e. a [mcve]?

Comment: I'm getting data from database in DataTable (as above). XML desired output is also shown above

Comment: using DataTable.ToXml , I get 4  xml rows and Have modified code to convert Segment, Price and Qty into subnode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from the bitmap in your question whether you intially have a `DataTable` or an `XDocument`.  So let's assume you have an `XDocument`, and you would like to group the child rows of the root element by the values of their first four columns, with the remaining values collected under a sequence of elements named `<BID_INTERVALS>`.

This can be accomplished using the following extension method:

```
public static partial class XNodeExtensions
{
    public static XElement CopyAndGroupChildrenByColumns(this XElement root, Func<XName, int, bool> columnFilter, XName groupName) =>
        new XElement(root.Name, 
                     root.Attributes(),
                     root.Elements()
                     .Select((row) => (row, key : row.Elements().Where((e, i) => columnFilter(e.Name, i)).Select(e => (e.Name, e.Value)).ToHashSet()))
                     .GroupByKeyAndSet(pair => pair.row.Name, pair => pair.key)
                     .Select(g => new XElement(g.Key.Key, 
                                               g.Key.Set.Select(p => new XElement(p.Name, p.Value)).Concat(g.Select(i => new XElement(groupName, i.row.Elements().Where((e, i) => !columnFilter(e.Name, i))))))));

    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<(TKey Key, HashSet<TItem> Set), TSource>> GroupByKeyAndSet<TSource, TKey, TItem>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, HashSet<TItem>> setSelector) =>
        Enumerable.GroupBy(source, (i) => (keySelector(i), setSelector(i)), new CombinedComparer<TKey, HashSet<TItem>>(null, HashSet<TItem>.CreateSetComparer()));
}

public class CombinedComparer<T1, T2> : IEqualityComparer<ValueTuple<T1, T2>>
{
    readonly IEqualityComparer<T1> comparer1;
    readonly IEqualityComparer<T2> comparer2;
    public CombinedComparer(IEqualityComparer<T1> comparer1, IEqualityComparer<T2> comparer2) => (this.comparer1, this.comparer2) = (comparer1 ?? EqualityComparer<T1>.Default, comparer2 ?? EqualityComparer<T2>.Default);
    public bool Equals(ValueTuple<T1, T2> x, ValueTuple<T1, T2> y) => comparer1.Equals(x.Item1, y.Item1) && comparer2.Equals(x.Item2, y.Item2);
    public int GetHashCode(ValueTuple<T1, T2> obj) => HashCode.Combine(comparer1.GetHashCode(obj.Item1), comparer2.GetHashCode(obj.Item2));
}
```

Then, given some `XDocument doc`, you can do:

```
// Group by the first four columns with all remaining elements collected under a <BID_INTERVALS> sequence of elements:
XName groupName = doc.Root.Name.Namespace + "BID_INTERVALS";
var grouped = doc.Root.CopyAndGroupChildrenByColumns((n, i) => (i < 4), groupName);

var newDoc = new XDocument(grouped);
```

If, on the other hand, you have a `DataTable dt` not an `XDocument`, you can convert the table to an `XDocument` directly using the following extension method:

```
public static partial class XNodeExtensions
{
    public static XDocument ToXDocument(this DataTable dt, XmlWriteMode mode = XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema)
    {
        var doc = new XDocument();
        using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
            dt.WriteXml(writer, mode);
        return doc;
    }
}
```

And then do:

```
var doc = dt.ToXDocument(XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JNNlOa).